# Read and display selected rows in datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, datareader

I have created a datatable that displays the data which is gathered from the datareader. My problem is it does not display all the rows that are being selected. It only displays one row.How can I display all the rows that are being selected?

## Code Behind

```
        int Quantity;
        string JobName;
        string OrderType;
        DateTime DueDate;
  
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString);

        string cmdText = "SELECT Quantity,Job_Name,[Order],Due_Date FROM Shopping_Cart WHERE UID=@UIDD";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);

        //===== Adding parameters/Values.
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UIDD", hfUserID.Value);

        //===== To check current state of the connection object. If it is closed open the connection
        //===== to execute the insert query.
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }

        //===== Execute Query.
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();
       
        Quantity = dr.GetInt32(0);
        JobName = dr.GetString(1);
        OrderType = dr.GetString(2);
        DueDate = dr.GetDateTime(3);
        
        con.Close();
        if (Session["UID"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4] {
                            new DataColumn("QUANTITY", typeof(string)),
                            new DataColumn("JOB NAME", typeof(string)),
                            new DataColumn("ORDER TYPE", typeof(string)),
                       
                            new DataColumn("DUE DATE", typeof(string))});
         
            dt.Rows.Add(Quantity, JobName, OrderType, DueDate);

  YourTable.Append("<table border = '1'>");
            YourTable.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                YourTable.Append("<th style = 'background-color: #0bd2d1;color:#ffffff'>");
                YourTable.Append(column.ColumnName);
                YourTable.Append("</th>");
            }
            YourTable.Append("</tr>");
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                YourTable.Append("<tr>");
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    YourTable.Append("<td>");
                    YourTable.Append(row[column]);
                    YourTable.Append("</td>");
                }
                YourTable.Append("</tr>");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than

```
dr.Read()
```

use

```
while(dr.Read())
{

   // Do stuff
}
```

That way it will loop over all rows in the DataReader.